# CSS grid - Text box over an image

Tags: html, css

I am working with a CSS grid, and at the moment I am trying to make a white box over an image, that have to contain some text. But I am really not sure how to do this the correct way. This is how I would like the layout to look like:

**Larger screens:**

[image]

**Mobile devies:**
[image]

I am working with this specific row. But I really do not know how to start this part. Does anybody have an idea how this can be done?

```
.sbp-item12 {
    grid-row: 6 / 7;
    grid-column: 1/13;
    height: 400px;
    background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/fQvhtmj/234234.jpg");
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) { 
    .sbp-item12 {
        grid-row: 9 / 10;
        grid-column: 1/13;
        height: 600px;
        background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/fQvhtmj/234234.jpg");
    }

}

<div class="sbp-item12">item 12</div>
```

Comment: You don't need CSS Grid to achieve this, is Grid necessary ?

Comment: Thanks for the comment @ZohirSalak. I am using the CSS grid to build up a page, so I would like to keep the syntax clean of the page. But true what you are saying maybe. The question was just ment, how am I doing this the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to add a separate id (or class) which defines the box. In this case I added `#textbox`, specifying the postion, padding, background and text colors (to stand out against the image).  Then I nested a `<div id="textbox">` inside your `<div class="sbp-item12">`.  That will work for your larger screens. You will need to fiddle with it if you want `#textbox` to slide under the image for mobile screens (as I don't know how this would affect your grid rows and columns).

```css
.sbp-item12 {
    grid-row: 6 / 7;
    grid-column: 1/13;
    height: 400px;
    background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/fQvhtmj/234234.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#textbox {
  position: absolute;
  top: 130px;
  left: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color:#BFBFBF;
  color:#000;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) { 
    .sbp-item12 {
        grid-row: 9 / 10;
        grid-column: 1/13;
        height: 600px;
        background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/fQvhtmj/234234.jpg");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }

    #textbox {
        position: absolute;
        top: 130px;
        left: 50px;
        padding: 10px;
        background-color:#BFBFBF;
        color:#000;
}

}
```

```html
<div class="sbp-item12">
  <div id="textbox">item 12 is just something to say to fill up some space for this example</div>
</div>
```

(also added `background-repeat: no-repeat;` to prevent image from tiling.)